# Spring-WS: SimpleWsdl11Definition with a multi-node taxonomy for WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, spring-ws

Spring-WS 1.5:  Using SimpleWsdl11Definition, exposing a WSDL is straightforward (from Spring-WS doc) in XML configuration:

```
<bean id="orders" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
    <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/wsdl/Orders.wsdl"/>
</bean>
```

Yields a URL exposing the WSDL at:

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-ws/orders.wsdl
```

The SimpleWsdl11Definition bean id + ".wsdl" becomes the leaf of the WSDL's URL when deployed, which covers a single-node taxonomy.

I need to support exposure of WSDLs that have multi-node taxonomies.

For instance:

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-ws/domain/subdomain/foo.wsdl
```

How is this accomplished in Spring-WS?  Bean ID attributes do not allow "/" characters, so I wonder what ways exist to influence the WSDL URL.

Note:  Using generated WSDLs will not be on option (for backward-consistency reasons), for instance with DefaultWsdl11Definition.  As with SimpleWsdl11Definition, I'd like to map requests for the WSDL to the static WSDL.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "multi-node taxonomies" mean?

Comment: Single-node: *root*/leaf
Multi-node:  *root*/branch/subbranch/leaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After poking around spring-ws source, I found there is no support for exposing a multi-node path for static-sourced WSDL configuration.

So I subclassed MessageDispatcherServlet and SimpleWsdl11Definition, and in my servlet, provided my own WSDL-request mapper that supports existing WsdlDefinition beans, as well as my "location-specified" WsdlDefinition bean.

Yields ability to configure in this sort of manner:

```
<!-- exposes URL:  host/context-root/servlet-name/MyService.wsdl -->
<bean id="MyService" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
    <property name="wsdl" value="/WEB-INF/wsdl/MyService.wsdl" />
</bean>

<!-- exposes URL:  host/context-root/servlet-name/some/multi/node/taxonomy/path/MyService.wsdl -->
<bean id="MyService.otherVersion" class="path.to.my.EnhancedWsdl11Definition">
    <property name="wsdl" value="/WEB-INF/wsdl/otherVersion/MyService.wsdl" />
    <property name="locationUri" value="some/multi/node/taxonomy/path/MyService.wsdl" />
</bean>
```

All is well.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem exposing two versions of a webservice with different urls.

```
old version within http://hostname/ws.wsdl
new version within http://hostname/version/ws.wsdl
```

My solution was not using the generic org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServletservlet but the default org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet and configuring the url mappings to the different wsdl versions in my bean config.

**I prefer this solution because it works without subclassing any spring classes.**

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>webservice</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webservice</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/ws.wsdl</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/version/ws</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/version/ws.wsdl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

beans.xml

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageFactory" ref="messageFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageDispatcher"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/ws.wsdl">ws</prop>
            <prop key="/version/ws.wsdl">ws-newversion</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultHandler" ref="messageDispatcher" />
</bean>

<bean id="ws"
    class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:wsdl/oldversion/Service.wsdl" />
</bean>

<bean id="ws-newversion"
    class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:wsdl/newversion/CarService.wsdl" />
</bean>
```

Thus each wsdl is exposed at the given path configured in the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping-Bean.